# make telegram bot using python

Tags: python, telegram, xlsx, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a telegram bot using python, but for some reason it doesn't post the info to the telegram. my code is supposed to send a data frame to telegram as a table but it returns noting(even a error) when I call it from telegram.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, InlineQueryHandler, CommandHandler
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

def get_data():
    data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/data.xlsx')# opening xlsx file as the input 
    data = data.to_string(columns = ['c.1', 'c.2'], index = False, header = True, line_width = 70, justify = 'left')
    return data

def result(bot, update):
    data = get_data()
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, table=data)
    bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=data)

def main():
    updater = Updater('Token key')
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('result',result))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the new CallbackContext? There should be an message linking to this page: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0) when starting the bot. There it says:

> Now on to the bulk of the change. You wanna change all your callback functions from the following:

```
def start(bot, update, args, job_queue):
    # Stuff here
```

> to the new style using CallbackContext

```
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    # Stuff here
    # args will be available as context.args
    # jobqueue will be available as context.jobqueue
```

I got it to work with a minimal example like this:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, InlineQueryHandler, CommandHandler

def result(update, context):
    print('result called')
    data = 'mydata'
    update.message.reply_text(data)

def main():
    updater = Updater('Token', use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('result',result))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

P.S.: You don't seem to use the `requests` and `re` from the imports.